# Link domain to multilangual website

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, redirect, multilingual

I want to create domain names for different country's and link them to my wordpress website redirecting to the right language.

So my question is:
How can I link my domain name `somedomain.it` to `somedomain.com/it`?

I am using a wordpress website, currently hosted at hostgator.
The website handles the multilangual support trough weglot.

I hope someone has any idea how to make this work or got an alternative option.

Thanks in advance!
- Tjeu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with apache!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ somedomain\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somedomain.com/it/$1 [R=301,L]
```